# ios, code-reuse issue, reuse viewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, controller

I have a view controller(A) which shows a list of items download from server.

I have another view controller(B) with segmented control.
When second index of segmentedControl is selected, the view controller(B) shows a list of items in the same format as in the controller(A).
When first index of segmentedControl is selected, the view controller(B) shows the items in different format.

I want A and B share a code for the common stuff.

I first thought ok I could move all the view-related code to "common_view class" and use the view class from both controllers.
But, it turns out that there are codes which are not related to view(such as downloading stuff from server, which is controller-part of mvc pattern).

Now I'm perplexed, "is it a good idea to share a controller-part code? is it even possible?"

I could factor out a common code into a commonViewController, and instantiate it from controller(A) and controller(B), and add commonViewController.view as a subview.
But is this really desirable? or do you suggest any better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can post that on *Code Review* (http://codereview.stackexchange.com) ? One of the purpose of this site is for questions about "Best practices and design pattern usage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes definitely..you can.Use two NIBS in this case.The first NIB wil be used by ViewController A and first segment of ViewController B.On selection of second segment in ViewController B addSubView of viewControllerA which initsWithSecondNiB name.Once you have added them ,control their visibility by show/hide when toggling between between the two segments of viewcontrollerB

Comment: thanks, ViewController(A) and viewController(B) having commonViewController as an instance variable looks ok then?